# rxjs not getting data from behaviour subject on switchmap and refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  posts = [
    { id: 1, name: 'chethan' },
    { id: 2, name: 'rohan' },
    { id: 3, name: 'sai' },
    { id: 4, name: 'yashas' },
  ];

  constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {}

  getPosts() {
    return of(this.posts);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.myData$.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('from mydata');
      console.log(data);
    });

    // this.testService.mysecondData$.subscribe((data) => {
    //   console.log('from secondata');
    //   console.log(data);
    // });

    this.testService.refresh();
    this.testService.emitProduct(3);
  }
}
```

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  map,
  Subject,
  switchMap,
  switchMapTo,
  tap,
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  private refreshSubject = new Subject<void>();
  refresh$ = this.refreshSubject.asObservable();

  private productSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  product$ = this.refreshSubject.asObservable();

  mysecondData$ = this.product$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('coming to mysecondata')),
    map(() => 5)
  );

  myData$ = this.refresh$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('myData before switchmap got refresh pipe')),
    switchMap(() => this.mysecondData$),
    tap(() => console.log('myData after switchmap bypassed refresh pipe'))
  );

  emitProduct(data: number) {
    this.productSubject.next(data);
  }

  refresh() {
    this.refreshSubject.next();
  }
}
```

when i check the output i am not able to get the emission of product$

**i understand that refresh will fire then it should switch to product$ which emits 5 but i am not seeing that output, which is it not emitting values even thought i have used behaviour subject**?

even when i subscribe to this.testService.product$ from ngonit not getting any data, event after calling next() method of productSubject, why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code you just pasted is likely that the cause  is because `product$` is a derivation of `refreshSubject`  rather than `productSubject`.

Hence you're emitting new values into the `productSubject` but that isn't  wired to anything

Comment: lol GG,  lesson learnt do not copy paste

Comment: If this resolved your question don't forget to mark this answer as accepted  <3